# Loaded and unloaded solutions

Tags: organic-chemistry, aqueous-solution

What is the difference between a loaded solution and an unloaded solution? I was reading this article and I didn't understand these parts:

> - The reaction kinetics of $\ce{CO2}$ with **loaded** aqueous MEA solution...
> - $\ce{CO2}$ **loading** from $\mathrm{0-0.4~mole}~ \ce{CO2/ mole amine}$ for $30$ weight percent MEA solution...
> - kinetic constants are developed taking into account **loading**, temperature ...

Answer (score -1):

Unloaded solutions are solutions without absorbed $\ce{CO2}$ and loaded solutions contain absorbed $\ce{CO2}$.  Please see the [this link](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/26161/7/acs%252Ejced%252E5b00282.pdf).

Comment: This is an answer, so not deleteable.